# Adjust the resolution to Tablet

Tags: xcode, flutter

I made the application for iPhone.

It shows layout well, but on iPad Widget comes the same size as iPhone(so too small).

However I want to multiple size automatically on iPad

I opened `Runner.xcworkspace` and confirmed

Targets>>General>>Deployment Info >> `iPad` is checked.

Project>>Basic>>Deployment>>Target Device Family >> `Universal` is selected

Is there any place to check or it the problem for Xcode or flutter??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LayoutBuilder to listen to different sizes of the device and re-layout accordingly:

```
in your build methods:

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constrain){
    ... look into the constrain and change layout here...
    }
```

The `constrain` contains the current size

You can also ask for the size in `MediaQuery.of(context).size`

For more...there are many posts on the web like this one:
https://diveintoflutter.blogspot.com/2019/04/flutter-layoutbuilder.html

Comment: I did like this `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100 * 2`(set 2% of screen width) . It works for every resolution. thank you very much.